# Overdrawing on the toolbar? Alternative idea?

Tags: c++, c, wxwidgets, win32gui

Main aim is wanting to draw Tab's within the draw area of the Toolbar of the Applicaiton for a NoteBook or Tab's to use the above space instead of being bellow the toolbar.

The frame work we're using is WxWidgets, C++/C. I have looked around but have not been able to find a solution or if anyone has done a similar approach with drawing tab's actually inside the toolbar itself.

I read some Microsoft MSDN articles and they recommend against controls drawing over controls.

I did some test's today, and think I've come up with a solution. My solution is to draw the window like normal, but have the NoteBook on the right in a child window that is dynamically resized and repositioned so that it's tab's are overlay on-top of the toolbar to make the most effective use of the area. I would have to deal with on focus and lose focus window messages, but this is the most elegant way I can think about achieving the task.

Any Idea's you can recommend or problem's I may face with following this approach.

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 1):

I would be concerned about using overlapping widgets like this. Although it may not look quite the same visually I would suggest looking at [wxToolBook](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_toolbook.html) which puts tabs in a toolbar and would solve your problem, you could use the `GetToolBar` method to insert your own toolbar items.

If that wasn't close enough visually to what you are looking to achieve I would suggest deriving a new control from [wxBookCtrlBase](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_book_ctrl_base.html) and then creating a tab control with custom drawn tabs which you could add to the toolbar using [wxToolBar::AddControl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tool_bar.html#aec263a8e47372eb78e91b8db8797731d).